# Check if there were conflicts in post-rewrite hook

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, githooks

In the context of a `post-rewrite` hook, is there any way to know if the rebase that caused the hook to fire had conflicts that needed to be resolved, or did it simply replay changes?

Comment: you can always do a test like this: 'git log a ^b' or 'git log ^a b' depend on your branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The longer answer is still "No ... but you can get close, and maybe close enough, by *repeating the operation*.  But see caveats."

#### Generalization

Let's generalize this, so that we are not just talking about a post-rewrite hook, because this problem also applies to repeating a `git rebase` (re-rebasing after fixing a log message, for instance) or doing a `git rebase -p` (preserve merges, which must repeat an earlier merge).

Whenever Git invokes its three-way-merge machinery, what it does amounts to:

```
ours=$(git rev-parse HEAD) # or equivalent
theirs=$(git rev-parse $something_else)
base=$(something) # usually git merge-base, but this varies as well
git diff $base $ours > our.change
git diff $base $theirs > their.change
combine_our_change_and_their_change
```

(written in pseudo-shell).

For a regular `git merge`, the `base=$(something)` part really does use `git merge-base`, or rather, use the same code that `git merge-base` lets you use.  Exactly *how* it uses it depends on the merge strategy:

- For `-s resolve`, Git picks one of the merge bases the same way `git merge-base` does and uses that.
- For `-s recursive`, Git picks *all* of the merge bases, merging them (recursively, using their own merge bases to do *these* merges) to arrive at a "virtual merge base".  In most cases there's only one merge base anyway, which means that this does the same thing as `-s resolve` anyway.  In most of the remaining cases, there are two merge bases, and merging those two merge bases produces the same thing as picking one of those two merge bases at random, which means that this *still* does the same thing as `-s resolve`.  In a few cases, merging the merge bases produces something that is slightly different from either merge base, and in particularly problematic cases, merging the merge bases results in a merge conflict, and in cases that probably arise only in carefully-contrived scenarios using hand-constructed multidimensional commit graphs, we can have more than two merge bases and things get really wild.  But mostly this just does the same thing as `-s resolve`.
- For `-s ours`, Git doesn't actually do a merge at all, and the whole issue goes away.
- For `-s octopus`, Git finds a multiway merge base, aborts the merge if there are conflicts, and finishes only if there are no merge conflicts, so that the problem vanishes in much the same way as for `-s ours`.

What this boils down to is that we need to know which strategy was used.  Unfortunately, Git does not record this information anyway.  So that's caveat #1.  We can guess that the strategy was `-s recursive` if there are two merge parents, and `-s octopus` if there were more than two, but that's just a guess.<sup>1</sup>

This is all useful (to whatever extent) if the merge was made by `git merge`, but what if a three-way merge operation was the result of `git apply -3` or something equivalent?  In this case the `base` may not be a *commit* at all, and rather than two `git diff` commands to compare two *commits*, we *may* just want to do the equivalent of:

```
git merge-file $options $ourfile $basefile $theirfile
```

Finding the three files in question is a bit tricky.  In the easy case they all have the same names in three commits, and/or, we have full blob hash IDs so that we can extract the file contents by hash ID and not have to worry about path-names.  We still have an issue with `$options`, which can be one of:

- nothing: a normal merge: stop with a conflict in the case of conflicts
- `--ours`: a `-X ours` argument to `git merge` or equivalent: favor "ours" in the case of conflicts
- `--theirs`: a `-X theirs` argument to `git merge` or equivalent: favor "theirs" in the case of conflicts
- `--union`: do a union merge (can only be specified via `.gitattributes`, currently, and union merges always succeed even if there would be conflicts)

As with the strategy, Git fails to record this information.  That's caveat #2: when repeating the operation, you must guess at the additional strategy arguments.

Caveat #3 is `git rerere`: in the case of a conflict, Git may *re*use a *re*corded *re*solution and hence you will not *see* a conflict.  Whether this is significant for you depends on your goals / needs.

#### Applied in post-rewrite hook

Now let's go back to specifically [the post-rewrite hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_rewrite).  This hook is currently invoked only after doing `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`, and it can tell *which command was used* by inspecting its arguments.

It then receives, on standard input, a list of rewrites:

> ```
> <old-sha1> SP <new-sha1> [ SP <extra-info> ] LF
> ```
>
> The extra-info is again command-dependent. If it is empty, the
>     preceding SP is also omitted. Currently, no commands pass any
>     extra-info.

This "extra info" could be where we might get some of the missing items (strategy and options, for instance)—but we don't.  We do, however, know that rebase essentially does a series of cherry-picks.  It also uses a full commit-wide diff by default (`-m` or `--merge`, etc) so as to detect renames.  In other words, we want the two-git-diffs-against-a-base method when we locate the file names to give to `git merge-file` in order to repeat any given file-level merge operation.

We don't necessarily even have to go that far.  We have the two commit hashes: the original commit that was to be cherry-picked, and the new resulting commit.  We could just switch to a temporary branch—an anonymous detached HEAD, for instance—and a temporary work tree, and do another `git cherry-pick` of the original commit (the old SHA1) onto the parent of the new commit (new SHA1 plus hat suffix), using `-n` to prevent the commit itself, and look to see if there are conflicts.  Modulo all our caveats, this may let us see if the user had to resolve some conflicts.

We must, however, beware of yet another issue with `git rebase`: an *interactive* rebase allows the user to `squash` or `fixup` several original commits into one single final new commit.  Quoting the githooks documentation again:

> For the *squash* and *fixup* operation, all commits that were squashed are listed as being rewritten to the squashed commit. This means that there will be several lines sharing the same *new-sha1*.

It's possible that some intermediate results (from applying one or more original commits) have or lack some conflict(s) that are gone from, or now appear in, the final rewritten commit, respectively.  It's not at all clear to me what you would like to do for these cases.  (For that matter, it is not at all clear to me what you want to do with "there were/weren't conflicts to resolve" in the first place!)

---

<sup>1</sup>If a merge *commit* was created by `git merge`, *and* it has more than two parents, it was definitely from either `-s ours` or `-s octopus`.  The other merge strategies can only resolve two "heads" (commits treated as if they were the tip of a branch).  But we can create merge *commits* without running `git merge` at all.  The `git stash` command does this, for instance.  These are not normal merges in any sense of the word: `git stash` is simply (ab?)using Git's various mechanisms to record a bunch of information in a convenient and compact form for later un-stashing.  Nonetheless, some of the commit objects `git stash` makes are merge *commits*.

Comment: Wow, thank you!

What I want to do is to check if a specific file was changed after a `git pull --rebase` and do something if it did.

I can generally do that with a `post-checkout` hook, but not if there were conflicts, because it is called _before_ the conflicts are resolved.

The best solution I managed to come up with until now, which isn't so elegant, is to check if I am in the middle of a rebase in the `post-checkout` hook (check existence of`.git/reabse-merge dir), and create an empty file in the `.git` dir, which I can check the presence of in the `post-rewrite` hook.

Comment: Ah, so, it sounds like you want to scan through the sha1 pairs, find the "replacement sha1" for each "original sha1", and then just do `git diff --name-status old-sha1 new-sha1` and see if the path name of interest turns up. That's considerably simpler.

Comment: Well, Yes, but only if there was a conflict. The problem is that `post-rewrite` only runs after replay or conflict, so if `git pull --rebase` simply does a fast-forward, it will not run, which is why I have to relay on `post-checkout`, and fallback to `post rewrite` only if there was a conflict. That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: Ah, so you don't care whether *you* modified some file(s), but rather, whether *anyone* modified some file(s). This means you are using the wrong tool. I'm still not sure precisely what you are doing, but in general, in the kind of code I work on, we would have a Makefile and a rule including `processed_result: source_file` and `processed_result` would not be in the VCS at all (would be in `.gitignore`). Then after doing any work, `make` would know to build or rebuild `processed_result`, because `source_file` would be newer.

Comment: I'm trying to keep dependencies updated across team members, so that, for instance, `npm install` will be automatically run when `package.json` is updated after a `pull`. It'd be pretty easy to achieve with a `post-merge` hook, but we use `pull --rebase` as out default, so the `post-merge` hook is not called.